# Angular JS: Translating static html pages with a lot of text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, angular-translate

I'm currently localizing my Angular site and [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) seems to be a good option for smaller strings. However I have a few pages with a lot of static html content like the ToS or the about page that I don't really want to cram into a JSON file (mixed with html tags etc).

So is there a way to use angular-translate (or even without that module) to save the content in partial views (like /partials/tos-en.html) and swap it out depending on the language?

Comment: Seems my answer missed the mark. The question is a little vague as to what you are looking for? A way to identify the different view? A way to save the data?

Comment: why not just use ng-include with html name from scope variable. set the variable as per the language and done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a way to get the user's language code. Having that, you intend to render a partial with the language code as part of the name.

***Angular translate*** module has 2 service methods of interest:

`$translate.use()` returns the user's active language. Unfortunately, if you call the service method before the language loads to the page, you may get null.

`$translate.proposedLanguage()` returns the "intended language" -- meaning the value you would get calling `$translate.use()`, but this call will succeed even if the language hasn't loaded. Having this list of **[language codes](http://ctrlq.org/code/19899-google-translate-languages)**, you can use them to create partials for languages you intend to support.

Something like

```
<div ng-include="about-{{ $translate.proposedLanguage() }}.html">
</div>
```

Comment: this seems like a very promising approach and I'll try that out asap, thx. How would you deal with unsupported languages / fallback to a default language?

Comment: @Thomas Default set to 'en' since English is almost universal.

Comment: Consider using database to store your "pages"with language codes. DB rows are easier to manage than folders of partials

Comment: For this project I'm not using a DB so I'm reluctant to to so at this point. 
Regarding the default language: How can I specify my supported languages?

Comment: @Thomas, my first thought is to have an array you define in your top level controller with all the languages you support. Then you can simply check if the return value is in your list. If not, default to 'en'.

Comment: At least in version 1.4.5 of Angular it doesn't work composing the src of the ng)include like you've put in your example. Tried different ways (like ng-src etc.) Best way in my eyes seems to listen for $translateChangeSuccess and recreate the url to your partial on each change and use that URL in your ng-include. See my seperate answer in this post.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going down the partial path you highlighted. Translating small chunks of text works for menu entries but ends up reading clumsily for an entire document. The translator needs to be able to vary things like sentence and paragraph structure for it to look natural.

To implement this I would use [Apache's content negotiation (mod_negotiation)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Your angular code remains simple, just refer to /partials/tos.html. Apache then provides tos.html.en, tos.html.fr or tos.html.de etc. as desired.

Setting up the content negotiation does require the use of Apache and the ability to edit the configuration files but isn't very complex to learn. I suggest also following the instructions to enable the prefer-language cookie, this allows you to provide a language selection mechanism which overrides the users browser language settings.

Answer (score 1):

Create an HTML partial for each language. Listen to the $translateChangeSuccess event in your controller and create the URL to the partial each time the language changes. Than use that URL in your view in an ngInclude directive.

***V2 better approach***

**Your controller**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translate) {
    ($scope.setTranslatedPartials = function () {
        $scope.translatedPartials = {
            "partialOne": "/partials/partial_one_" + $translate.use() + ".html",
            "partialTwo": "/partials/partial_two_" + $translate.use() + ".html"
            //...
        };
    })();

    $rootScope.$on("$translateChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
        $scope.setTranslatedPartials();
    });
}]);
```

**Your view**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ng-include src="translatedPartials.partialOne"></ng-include>
    <ng-include src="translatedPartials.partialTwo"></ng-include>
</div>
```

---

***V1 original approach***

**Your controller**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$translate', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translate) {
    /*Initialize first so you have it when coming back to the page without the langugage changing*/
    $scope.partial = "/partials/" + $translate.use() + ".html"

    $rootScope.$on("$translateChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
        $scope.partial = "/partials/" + $translate.use() + ".html"
    });
}]);
```

**Your view**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ng-include src="partial"></ng-include>
</div>
```